# Convert Mongo Datestamp to R readable date format.

Tags: r, rmongo

I pulled data into R from `MongoDB` and my dates are in the format string `"Thu May 08 01:00:00 EAT 2008"`. I want  to change them to format `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"` readable by `R` and been banging my head so far.

I came around using `DF$createdAt <- as.Date(DF$createdAt,format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")` but this turns all the years to current year 2013.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    createAt
     Thu May 08 01:00:00 EAT 2008
      Tue May 13 01:00:00 EAT 2008
      Tue May 13 01:00:00 EAT 2008
      Thu May 15 01:00:00 EAT 2008
     Mon May 19 01:00:00 EAT 2008
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `%Y` for the four-digit year.

```
fmt <- "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EAT %Y"
as.Date("Thu May 08 01:00:00 EAT 2008", fmt)
## [1] "2008-05-08"
strptime("Thu May 08 01:00:00 EAT 2008", fmt)
## [1] "2008-05-08 01:00:00"
```

When you come to print the values, use `strftime` or `format`, and specify how you would like the dates to look.